# Can't access postgres running in a separate docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be on ubuntu server 16.04 LTS.
I have a Postgres running in a container and exposing port 5432.

I can connect it from anywhere except a sibling container where psql just timeouts. As address, I use the host's IP. Ping from client works, psql connect doesn't.

I know I could create a docker-compose with combined Postgres service, but would rather not - I want to keep them totally separate.

Any idea how to troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put both container on the same docker network for them to able to talk to each other.

`docker network create funny`

Then start your container attaching to the network

`docker run database_container --net=funny --name=database`

`docker run app_container --net=funny --name=app`

Once you do that, you can connect to each container by the name you specify in the run command.

Comment: Yep, I ended doing that at the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want use `--net=host` for that.

Adding the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328300/accessing-hosts-virtual-machine-from-docker-container#answers-header) I got for a similar question:

For a quick work around you can run all the containers with flag `--net=host` which means the docker containers will use the host network interface. more info on docker networking can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

Comment: That might work but at the end the traefik won't play nicely with it. Good though though.

Answer (score 0):

Pass -c 'listen_addresses=*' to docker run command line this will allow postgress to accept connection from remote machine:

```
docker run --name postgres -p 5432:5432  -ePOSTGRES_DB=pgdb -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass -d postgres -c 'listen_addresses=*'
```

Comment: I had problem connecting from a sibling container, not remote machine.

Comment: your sibling is also remote if not in the same network, it will work with docker compose because docker compose creates a network. if you want to go without compose then you have to update listen_addresses as suggested. does it make sense?

Comment: I'm using compose. Anyway, placing both containers into the same network seems the cleanest and best option to me. Thanks anyway for suggestion.